# Photoshop CC 2014 Boot Loop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, troubleshooting

I'm a semi-professional photographer/university student. I specialize in Studio and On Location Portraiture--mostly glamour/fashion--and freelance a bit for local paper/businesses. Some sports and event photog for extra $$ lol. Lastly, I'm addicted to timelapses!

Ok, now that I've sort of introduced myself, I'm experiencing a very very VERY serious Photoshop CC 2014 issue.

For several days now, I've been stuck in a bootloop consisting of:

1. Open Photoshop CC 2014.app
2. PS splash screen appears (shows the usual text initiating stuff in the splash)
3. **Crash**

(can't remember when/what was the last event). although I believe it was around the time I was compiling a small focus stack in ps.

Anyway,

If it helps, the log file is here:

[PS Logfile](https://cloudup.com/cvegeT0XEGK)

Comment: adobe charge so much a month for creative cloud, why not call them and ask and report back? And try the obvious  - uninstalling and installing

Comment: the log says about a problem at some address so maybe you have a RAM issue. But I guess mac users don't try opening up their pretty computers.

Comment: give this a try: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3734077?start=0